# How to do OCR for multi page using (Python + AWS Textract )

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-textract

I am using the following code to get the AWS texttract response, but I can't get any results.
If someone already has a way to extract information from invoices and receipts. I would appreciate it if you can advise me.

```
def start_analysis_job(bucket_name, document_file_name):
       try:
            response = textract.start_document_analysis(
                DocumentLocation={
                    'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Name': document_file_name}},
                FeatureTypes=['TABLES'|'FORMS'],
            )
            job_id = response['JobId']
            logger.info(
                "Started text analysis job %s on %s.", job_id, document_file_name)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't analyze text in %s.", document_file_name)
            raise
        else:
            return job_id

def get_analysis_job(job_id):
        try:
            response = textract.get_document_analysis(
                JobId=job_id)
            job_status = response['JobStatus']
            logger.info("Job %s status is %s.", job_id, job_status)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't get data for job %s.", job_id)
            raise
        else:
            return response
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe what happens now? What results are you seeing? This may make it easier for people to understand the problem.